# Hausdorff Distance 2D

Tags: python

i am new to programming and currently working with Python. Can someone explain to me why is it that by changing the order of variable will end up with different results as compared to Euclidean distance obtaining the same results?

Below is the array i used for this experiment to understand the use
`u = np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [-1.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0]])`
`v = np.array([[2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0], [-2.0, 0.0], [0.0, -4.0]])`

`(directed_hausdorff(u, v)[:]))` --> output = (2.23606797749979, 3, 0) and
`(directed_hausdorff(v, u)[:]))` --> output = v,u = (3.0, 3, 3)

Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, this is how mathematically the two distances behave, the Hausdorff is not necessary symmetric

Comment: I see. So can i take it as the maximum distance between the 2 set of 2D coordinates is 3.0 in this case for (v,u) and 2.23 for (u, v)?

Comment: Yes - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.directed_hausdorff.html The documentation has this as an example even, lucky you!

Comment: @user3184950 Thank you! just one last question from me, as i will be using Hausdorff Distance to inspect the dissimilarity between a original profile (set A) and after operating profile (set B). How do i know which set of profile variable should come first in the code? Will it be `(directed_hausdorff(A, B)) or (directed_hausdorff(B,A))` for comparing the distance.

Comment: I am not an expert on that- Usually each distance has its benefit. I would try on historic cases you feel confident on which distance 'feels' or proves to be the best. This will probably give you confidence you have the right distance metric.